# Continuous current op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, dac, feedback

I'm using an [LMC7101 op-amp](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LMC7101-Low-Power-Operational-Amplifier-DS20006282A.pdf).  V+ is 5 V and V- is 0 V.

I want to know whether the op-amp can provide continuous current output (100 mA) while the input voltage is coming from a DAC ranging 0 to 2 V with 10 mA current. We are using it as a voltage feedback function along with maximum current output.

Comment: I wouldn't load any op amp's output with 100mA unless it's specified as safe to do so. I couldn't understand the application but you may consider using a totem pole as it can provide unity voltage gain and higher current gain.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But could you tell me why I cant load 100mA as the continuous load. In the Table LM7101A 5.0V Electrical Characteristics table, there it is mentioned as Output Short Supply Current as min of 120mA/80mA? So, its safe right? Or am I misunderstanding it? What does or when does Output Short Supply current occurs? @RohatKılıç

Comment: Also, in the same output short supply current , the values are given for Sourcing (Vout=0V) and Sinking (Vout=5V)? Shouldn't it be vice versa? Souring when Vout=5V and Sinking when Vout=0V?

Comment: Or just in general, can you tell me how much current can I get from the op-amp's output? How to find it in the datasheet?

Comment: The datasheet has a subnote on short circuit current in that the thermal parameters may be exceeded. Have a look at the voltage swing specs - nowhere near a 100mA load. A 100mA load is 50Ohms. You wont get much opamp action from this chip into that load. Try looking at an audio amp chip - that should have better current drive.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to reverse calculate the maximum output current that the op-amp can provide (For Vcc=5V and Isc = 120mA) with thermal resistance (325) value and ambient temperature(25degC), but still the junction temperature is failing. How to understand this value of Isc =120mA and Isc=200mA when putting those value on that equation fails clearly?

Comment: @Kartman , can you please explain how to interpret the output voltage swing spec? How did you say the 100mA load is 50ohms?

Comment: If the load on the output is 2k, then it is only guaranteed to get to x volts. Compare this to the volts at 10k load. Use some Ohms law to estimate what the output impedance is. What it tells me is don’t expect more than a couple of mA out whilst still getting reasonable voltage swing.

Comment: For my load current of 100mA, with output of say 5V, then the output load impedance would be 50ohms. But in the output swing parameter, there is not condition where the values are given for an output imepdance of 50ohms? It is only given for 600ohm and 2k? How to interpret this?

Comment: Could you please draw the schematic you have in mind? It may help to see some details that we don't want you to miss.

Comment: Just a small clarification, my input to the non-inverting terminal of the op-amp is between 0-2V. So, since it's a voltage follower, the output of the op-amp will also swing between 0-2V right?

Now, why do we need to think about the output swing values in the table that has values around 5V?

@RohatKılıç added a small image. Please check. Also, just a clarification, how to calculate the maximum normal current that the op-amp can deliver when the output (actually following the input) is between 0-2V? Can you tell how to make an approximate safe calculations for normal conditions?

Comment: If you describe your load characteristics and the required voltage range at the output, we can suggest a circuit modification. For example, if the load is mostly resistive and fairly constant, and the voltage output range is 0-2V, then one transistor can boost your output. Maybe this should be a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** The thing you missed here is the fact that **the short circuit ratings are NOT given for continuous operation** and therefore they don't tell you anything about maximum continuous output current. Which means, just because the short circuit current is given as 120 mA (min) doesn't mean a **continuous** output current of 100mA is safe for the op amp.

The max output current and short circuit current can be comparable when the short circuit condition is given as "indefinite" or "continuous" in the datasheet (of course, there are still some limitations such as max supply voltage e.g. for supply voltages higher than a particular level a long-duration short circuit can be destructive).

---

The output configuration of an op amp is like following *(may vary from op amp to op amp but overall config is almost the same)*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH1mBI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is basically a totem pole output but with series emitter resistors. The ref voltages (an unknown voltage generated internally) are for biasing the output transistors. Although they can be combined to a single one for both of the transistors, I preferred to show separately for the sake of simplicity.

Each series emitter resistor, R<sub>e</sub>, is there to protect the respective output transistor as well as to define the max output current. If the unloaded output voltage is 5V, the max current defined by R<sub>e</sub> and V<sub>BE</sub> of the Q1 will flow when the output is shorted to ground. Likewise, if the unloaded output voltage is 5V and if you load the output with say, 600 Ohms, then a non-zero voltage will drop across the collector-emitter of Q1 and the series emitter resistor. This is where the max voltage swing ratings come from *(Note: collector-emitter drop of a BJT changes with collector current)*.

---

Now let's make a rough calculation for your case: If your follower configuration forces the output voltage to be 2V at 100 mA output current then the total voltage drop across R<sub>e</sub> and Q1 will be supply voltage minus the output voltage i.e. 5V - 2V = 3V. At 100 mA output current the total dissipation will be 0.3 W *(neglecting the dissipation of previous sections)*. The thermal resistance is given as 325 °C per Watt which means a temperature rise of 325 x 0.3 = 97 °C **relative to ambient**. You won't be able to touch the op amp during normal operation, and it will be destroyed after a couple of minutes or even maybe seconds. That's why there's a note warning about potential destruction during short circuit.

The short circuit ratings do not always give an idea about maximum continuous output current.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've just two questions as asked in the comment previously. Like, since my output is going to be between 0-2V as the input will be from 0-2V, how to calculate the maximum safe value current that would be provided by the op-amp? And also, in the table on page 8 of the DS, like, they have give Vout=+V/2 . Which means, is Vout=2.5V, if Vcc is 5V in my case? So, will the output voltage be 2.5V? But in the conditions column, they mention as OUTPUT HIGH? Does OUTPUT HIGH=4.9V or 4.85V as mentioned in the table? Could you please explain on how to interpret

Comment: @Newbie for your first question about max safe output current, it's difficult to estimate if not given in the datasheet. For example, short circuit and maximum continuous output currents are well defined for LM324. But we can't say the same thing for your op amp. For your second question, since there's "unless otherwise indicated" , you should ignore the +V/2 output condition for short circuit ratings. And output HIGH and LOW indicate basically the maximum and minimum voltage seen inside the op amp output section. They can be Vcc/Vee or close voltages.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. So, I guess that, 100mA is not a safe option to drive the load at an output of 2V.

Comment: Also, if the short circuit current is 120mA or 200mA, at that time, when can calculate the power dissipation, the junction temperature exceeds, right? So,won't the device get damaged? Then what is the purpose of providing the short circuit current? Could you please clarify ?

Comment: @Newbie well, short circuit current is quite useful for the designers to take into account for worst cases. For example, if the output of an op amp is open to the outer world (i.e. end-user access) then the connector/socket/jack can be selected for a possible short circuit. Likewise, various protections can be added to design if necessary. Or even these parameters can be used as a base for production test specs.

Comment: @Newbie and also, yes the device may damaged when the output is shorted, and it's already indicated as a footnote. Check the short circuit ratings and related footnotes.